# JavaFX - I don't understand how to make my TableView editable

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am creating a Food Calculator in Java (JavaFX) which should be able to re-calculate food elements like Protein, Carbohydrates and Fat (all TableView table columns) when the user confirms an edit in the TableView.

I don't know how to make my table cells editable. I don't understand the documentation at all.

This is how I am creating my columns. I've read that I should change the `setCellValueFactory` to `SetCellFactory` but I have no idea why or what should be passed as a parameter to that function. Where would I assign the Food fields to the table then?

```
TableColumn<Food, Float> tableFoodFat = new TableColumn<>("Fat");
tableFoodFat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fat"));
tableFoodFat.setMinWidth(100);
```

I am really confused. Could anybody here help me out with an answer in simple words? I can write the code myself, I just need to understand what and why I should change it.

**EDIT:** This works for columns containing String data - `tableFoodTitle.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Food>forTableColumn());` but it throws an error when I am trying to use this concept on columns with Float data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!  it makes you  table cells editable!

```
tableFoodFat.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConvert‌​er));
tableFoodFat.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Food, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Food, Float> t) {
                ((Food) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFOODFAT(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });
```

just pay atention here `setFOODFAT`

Hope it can help!

Comment: I get this then: `incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that Callback<TableColumn<S,String>,TableCell<S,String>> conforms to Callback<TableColumn<Food,Float>,TableCell<Food,Float>>
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Object declared in method <S>forTableColumn()`

Comment: Yeah, you have Float not String as I sent... try this...  

tableFoodFat.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(FloatStringConverter));
tableFoodFat.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Food, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Food, Float> t) {
                ((Food) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFOODFAT(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks but I think I figured it out myself, I just passed `new FloatStringConverter()` to the `forTableColumn` function and now it works. If it's gonna work in every part of my software I will go with my method and post it as an answer here. If it fails somewhere I will try your solution.

Comment: Indeed. If the item class provides a property getter method, e.g. `FloatProperty fatProperty()`, the `onEditCommit` part is unnecessary...